# How to use MS Access ODBC driver without installing it?

Tags: ms-access, odbc

Up until today our company workstations would typically have the MS Office ODBC drivers installed in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14
```

However, for some reason the configuration recently changed so that for example `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` now points to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16
```

Unfortunately the actual installation of the driver is still in the `OFFICE14` directory.

Is there any way to still use this driver to connect to Access?

I don't have admin access, so am looking for any possible work-around until tech-support acknowledge & resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't think you can - the installation (registry vs. file system) needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The driver will have to be installed and registered as an ODBC component. So far, I am aware of 3 ways to do so:

1. Use of `ODBCCONF.EXE` which resides in `\windows\system32\` and `\windows\syswow64`.
2. Use of `SQLInstallDriverEx()` API provided by `odbccp32.dll`.
3. Manually create the registry keys ([look at this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279778/1091753))

Comment: If you are interested, I have an open question for #2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683787/how-to-use-sqlinstalldriverex-in-c).