# Connect ODBC without driver installed

Tags: c++, database, odbc, database-connection

Is it possible to make ODBC connection without system-wide driver installed? Can I just point a DLL that contains the driver?

I use it in C++, 32bit, currently testing on Windows, and connect to the Firebird Database. I tried following connection string, that **doesn't work**:

```
constexpr auto DatabaseConnection =
//"DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;" //this works when driver installed
"UID=SYSDBA;"
"PWD=masterkey;"
"DBNAME=C:\\some\\path\\to\\database\\DB.FDB;"
"Client=C:\\Windows\\System32\\OdbcFb.dll;";
```

The error message: `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird ODBC Driver contains small static library (named `OdbcFb.lib`) that should be linked within the application. Under the hood it probably preloads the dll and registers it as a new driver somehow.
When such library is linked, the connection string that works is:

```
"DRIVER=OdbcFb.dll;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=masterkey;DBNAME=127.0.0.1:C:\\path\\DB.GDB;";
```

What surprised me, when you omit DRIVER it also works, choosing apriopriate driver by using some magic:

```
"UID=SYSDBA;PWD=masterkey;DBNAME=127.0.0.1:C:\\path\\DB.GDB;";
```

Note that:

- the `OdbcFb.dll` has to be visible for your application (be at the same directory or in system PATH)
- one should be aware of choosing apriopriate library architecture, namely 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: The magic is (very probably) `FileExtns` (details at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/install/driver-specification-subkeys)) which is [set](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird-odbc-driver/blob/master/SetupAttributes.h) to `*.fdb,*.gdb`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a DSN-less connection can be made to an un-registered ODBC Driver, by fully specifying the connect string.

This line, as used when the driver is installed properly --

```
"DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;"
```

-- which really should be this, to reference the driver by name --

```
"DRIVER={Firebird/InterBase(r) driver};"
```

-- should be changed to this --

```
"DRIVER=C:\\Windows\\System32\\OdbcFb.dll;"
```

It appears that if the `%PATH%` is not set correctly (to include the directory containing the `odbcfb.dll`) and/or if the FB driver is not registered with the MDAC driver manager, you must include the FB-specific `client` keyword pointing to the `odbcfb.dll`, in which case you should not need any reference to `odbcfb.lib`.

You may benefit from reading the driver's own documentation for [creating DSNs](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/driver_manuals/odbc/html/fbodbc205-config-windows.html) and for [DNSless connections](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/driver_manuals/odbc/html/fbodbc205-conn-params.html)...

Comment: setting path in Driver doesn't take any effect. The same error is displayed. I read somewhere that specifying driver path doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263138/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-driver-dll-directly-in-the-odbc-connection-string

Comment: @jaskmar - I've just posted an answer to that other question, which came to erroneous conclusion. (Simply, `Driver=C:/path/to/driver/library` works fine on Windows.)

Comment: I don't know if it is specific for Firebird, but giving path will not work without linking `OdbcFb.lib`.