# Connect using PostgreSQL ODBC without driver installed

Tags: postgresql, odbc, psqlodbc

I tried to connect using PostgreSQL ODBC(psqlODBC 12.0) without the driver installed on Windows x64.

I placed all the files below in a directory. They were extracted from a MSI file.

```
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libpq.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
msvcp140.dll
pgenlist.dll
pgenlist.pdb
pgenlista.dll
pgenlista.pdb
pgxalib.dll
psqlodbc30a.dll
psqlodbc30a.pdb
psqlodbc35w.dll
psqlodbc35w.pdb
vcruntime140.dll
```

The connection string is as follows.

```
"DRIVER=C:\\tmp\\psqlodbc35w.dll;SERVER=localhost;Port=5432;Database=dbname;Uid=user;Pwd=password;"
```

But that didn't work. The error message is

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

According to this question([Connect ODBC without driver installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826254/connect-odbc-without-driver-installed)), it seems possible to specify a driver DLL path instead of a driver name. Do I overlook anything?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the path without the double backslashes, i.e., `DRIVER=C:\tmp\psqlodbc35w.dll` ...?

Comment: I forgot to write the language. It's C++, so double backslahes are needed. The ODBC system DLL in the OS receives with single backslash. DRIVER=C:\tmp\psqlodbc35w.dll

Comment: Try adding the folder containing the DLLs to your Windows PATH environment variable.

Comment: Actually I put all the DLLs in the System32, but the same error occuurred. I also tried LoadLibrary("psqlodbc35w.dll") and it suceeded. DLL dependece was correctly resolved.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit Python?

Comment: No. I'm using Visual C++ x64.