# How to use SQLInstallDriverEx in C#?

Tags: c#, interop

How would I rewrite the following function in order to use it in `C#`? The function is part of `odbccp32.dll` and is used to install an `ODBC driver`.

```
BOOL SQLInstallDriverEx(  
     LPCSTR    lpszDriver,  
     LPCSTR    lpszPathIn,  
     LPSTR     lpszPathOut,  
     WORD      cbPathOutMax,  
     WORD *    pcbPathOut,  
     WORD      fRequest,  
     LPDWORD   lpdwUsageCount);
```

[SQLInstallDriverEx Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlinstalldriverex-function)

This is my attempt:

```
 [DllImport("odbccp32")]
 private static extern bool SQLInstallDriverEx(
      string lpszDriver,
      string lpszPathIn,
      out string lpszPathOut,
      ushort cbPathOutMax,
      out uint pcbPathOut,
      ushort fRequest,
      out uint lpdwUsageCount);
```

A sample usage would be deeply appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p/Invoke Toolkit generates the following:

```
[DllImport("odbccp32.dll")]
public static extern  bool SQLInstallDriverEx(
     [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpszDriver, 
     [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpszPathIn,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder lpszPathOut, 
     ushort cbPathOutMax, ref ushort pcbPathOut, ushort fRequest, ref uint lpdwUsageCount);

public const ushort ODBC_INSTALL_INQUIRY = 1;
public const ushort ODBC_INSTALL_COMPLETE = 2;
```

The `In/MarshalAs` attributes may not be necessary. `StringBuilder`s work for "out" strings as the marshaller knows how to convert under the hood. You need to call the method twice, once to resolve the path/path length and the second to pass those values in. That step can be skipped if you know these before hand, but the path *can* change from what you provide if the driver already exists or the path is too long. The second call requires that the `lpszPathOut` be non-null and `cbPathOutMax` be non-zero.

The driver description that you pass to the method is made up of a list of null-byte terminated strings. The list is terminated with a double null.

```
// if target path is null, it should default to the system directory
var targetPath = @"c:\windows\system32";
ushort len = 0; uint usageCount=0;

// replace this with your actual driver description, note the double \0 at the end
var driver = "Text\0Driver=TEXT.DLL\0Setup=TXTSETUP.DLL\0FileUsage=1\0"
           + "FileExtns=*.txt,*.csv\0\0";

var ret = SQLInstallDriverEx(driver, targetPath, null, 0, 
                 ref len, ODBC_INSTALL_INQUIRY, ref usageCount);
if (ret) {
    var sbPath = new StringBuilder(len);
    if (ret = SQLInstallDriverEx(driver, targetPath, sbPath, len, 
                 ref len, ODBC_INSTALL_COMPLETE, ref usageCount)) {

        // sbPath will now contain the actual path, which may be different 
        // if there is a previous installation or the path was truncated
        // perhaps check here if that was intended

        // usageCount will be updated by the system
   }
}

if (!ret) {
    // query SqlInstallerError(...) here
}
```

If the return value is `false`, you will need to call the `SqlInstallerError` method which you will have to import as well. Fortunately there is a p/invoke page for this method and how to call it available at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/odbccp32/SQLInstallerError.html. The error codes and what they mean are already outlined on the MSDN page you linked.

Note that you can skip the two-phase method call and call with `ODBC_INSTALL_COMPLETE` once, provided you have provided correct buffer/sizes.