# how to fix this issue: version "not marked" showing in "Driver" tab of ODBC Data source administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, odbc

I have created MSI installer for an ODBC driver using Visual studio Installer in 2017(it was earlier created in 2010). I am able to successfully install driver, create registry entries as part of the installation but in the "Driver" tab of ODBC Data Source its show "Not Marked" for version and company. BUt in control panel, it does show version and company name. I have tried with manually registry entries, but not worked for me. I am an administrator user, so no question of permission arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Summary***: The driver file must have proper version information. Ensure the version is there for the file as appropriate, in this case by using a **`VERSIONINFO`** resource
>   added via a **`resource file (.rc)`**.

---

***ODBCCONF.EXE***: The tool [**`ODBCCONF.EXE`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/odbcconf-exe?view=sql-server-2017) can apparently be used to register ODBC drivers ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708912/129130)). ***`By the way, do your drivers files have proper Product Version and File Version? (as in the files themselves, go to file properties)`***. Not sure if that is important or not.

***PowerShell cmdlets***: It appears the **`ODBCCONF.EXE`** tool is being removed from Windows soon (from Windows Data Access Components). It will be replaced by PowerShell CmdLets: [Windows Data Access Components (Windows DAC) cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/index?view=win10-ps).

---

[***Registry Locations***](https://superuser.com/a/713286/11906): Just for the record, there are several registry locations:

- ***64-Bit***: **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC`**
- ***32-Bit***: **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC`**

---

***Some Links***:

- [Another answer describing registry keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279778/129130)
- [How to register ODBC driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648252/how-to-register-odbc-driver)
- [Registry Entries for ODBC Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/install/registry-entries-for-odbc-components?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Driver Specification Subkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/install/driver-specification-subkeys?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks, Stein, and Sorry for the late reply, since had other high priority task showed up, But I have already tried all these before. Seems need to check with file version, there could be the chance to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Stein, I have resolved this issue. Yes, It does need to have version info for the driver file. To resolve it, I need to use VERSIONINFO resource, added resource file (.rc) and created the installer, and issue got resolved.

Comment: Great, I will update the answer to have that as a one line summary (for others who might find it). Thanks for letting us know.