# How to remove an ODBC driver/connector that was registered with odbcconf.exe

Tags: windows, odbc, driver, connector

I registered/installed an ODBC driver with the help of the `odbcconfig` command on Windows.
The command looked like this:

```
c:\> %systemroot%/syswow64/odbcconf /A {INSTALLDRIVER "Custom SQLite3 (32bit)|driver=c:\windows\SysWOW64\custom_sqlite3odbc.dll"}
```

How can I remove/uninstall this driver?

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279778/5883632) mentions `SQLRemoveDriver`. But this is not an executable like `odbcconfig`. So how can I remove the driver from my System in cmd or PowerShell (or GUI) without fiddle with registry and ini files manually?